# Передать параметр в jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc

Такая задача:
у меня есть массив типа String, содержащий коды клиентов которые я получаю методом getCodeClient.

Потом в базе oracle мне нужно получить таблицу с параметрами этих клиентов, таблица строиться на основании полученных выше кодов.

я по идее должен преобразовать массив в такой список {'code012','code876','code123', ит.д.}

как передать этот список в jdbc чтобы потом использовать в запросе?

Comment: А `SELECT * FROM "TABLE_NAME" WHERE CODE="code012"` не пробовали?

Comment: мне нужно пережать сразу весь массив строк

Comment: Тогда `SELECT * FROM "TABLE_NAME" WHERE CODE="code012" or CODE="code876" ...`. Получите все строки из БД

Comment: получается нужно в ручную прописать CODE="code012" or CODE="code876" ... or ...or ...or ?

Comment: не вручную конечно.

Comment: Можно пользоваться конкетенацией или StringBuilder'ом

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вынужден поправить предыдущих ораторов. Все верно кроме одного, формирование почти одинаковых запросов без применения `PreparedStatement` является антипаттерном.

Поясняю. `PreparedStatement` просьба о прекомпиляции устойчивого SQL выражения, так что при следующем вызове СУБД не будет заново компилировать SQL запрос, а будет только менять параметры вызова извлекая запрос из своего кэша, что значительно быстрее по времени + бонусом защита от [SQL injection](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0)

Ближе к коду:

```
String selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE CODE = ?";
String whereClause="blah-blah";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(selectSQL);
```

И вот теперь уже можно формировать строку `whereClause`  методом предложенным @Виктор через `StringJoiner` или `StringBuilder` подставляя его в `PreparedStatement` и вызывая собственно сам запрос (не меняя каждый раз объект `PreparedStatement`):

```
preparedStatement.setString(1, whereClause);
ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery(selectSQL );
```

Comment: Согласен насчет `PreparedStatement`. +1

Comment: @Barmaley я так понял проблема в том, что автор не знает сколько кодов придет в метод и ему нужен динамический запрос. Если пришел 1 код то искать по 1, если 3 то искать по 3. PreparedStatement может так сделать?

Answer (score 1):

по мотивам предложения из комментария:

```
public Client getClient(String... params){
    StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder("SELECT * FROM \"TABLE_NAME\"");
    StringJoiner join = new StringJoiner(" or ");
    for(String param : params){
      join.add(param);
    }

    String queryParams = join.toString();

    if (!queryParam.isEmpty()){
        query.append(" WHERE ");
        query.append(queryParams);
    }

    ...//дальше логика вашего запроса, а формирование запроса можно 
       //вынести в отдельный приватный метод.
}
```